# Safe include of C code in a c++ object wrapper

Tags: c++

I have a C library which defines a type, say, `myCtype`, together with some routines which use a variable of `myCtype` type. I would like to define a C++ object as a wrapper for a single `myCtype` variable. Let us assume that the C header containing the definition of `myCtype` is `myCtype.h`. A C++ code with header `mywrapper.hpp` and code implementation in `mywrapper.cpp` would look like

`mywrapper.hpp`:

```
extern "C" {
#include "myCtype.h"
}

class mywrapper
{
    myCtype v;
    public:
    //...
    // Constructor and some methods here
    // ...
}
```

`mywrapper.cpp`:

```
#include "mywrapper.hpp"

// ...
// Constructor and methods of mywrapper here
// ...
```

The problem with this approach is that the C header `myCtype.h` may contain several "C-style" macros, definition and inline functions which may potentially clash with the rest of the C++ code. `mywrapper.hpp` needs to include `myCtype.h` because of the definition of `myCtype`. Thus, whenever I want to use `mywrapper` is a C++ code I would need to include `mywrapper.hpp`, and this brings together the unwanted `myCtype.h`.
Even if definitions and inline functions of `myCtype.h` do not clash with the current C++ code, it would be desirable to hide them from the C++ code.

Notice that I do not need the `myCtype` member `mywrapper::v` to be visible, as I declared it private. So, for all purposes, a C++ code using `mywrapper` could completely ignore the contents of `myCtype.h`

One solution to this problem could be to use a `void *` pointer to hold an instance of `myCtype`, as follows.

`mywrapper.hpp`:

```
class mywrapper
{
    void *v;
    public:
    mywrapper();
    virtual ~mywrapper();
    //...
    // some methods here
    // ...
}
```

`mywrapper.cpp`:

```
#include "mywrapper.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>
extern "C" {
     #include "myCtype.h"
}

mywrapper::mywrapper() : v(malloc(sizeof(myCtype)))
{
    // Some initialization of v here
}

virtual mywrapper::~mywrapper()
{
    free(v);
}

// ...
// Methods of mywrapper here
// ...
```

Now only the compile unit of `mywrapper.cpp` includes `myCtype.h`, and a C++ code including `mywrapper.hpp` does not bring `myCtype.h` along.
This solution however comes with type unsafety of using a `void *` pointer.

Is there a better solution? It should:

- Wrap the C library in a C++ object wrapper
- "Hide" the C header `myCtype.h` in a separate compile unit,
  independent from the C++ code using the wrapper
- Ensure type safety everywhere

Comment: `extern "C"` does not mean you have C code, it changes just the ABI. And headers are not a library, you want to learn what a header actually is, it's relevant to understand your problem.

Comment: That C header should be fixed then so it won't clash with C++ (and other C) code. You may or may not want to isolate it so there is no "better" option here.

Comment: I am not sure I get the criticism. 1) Of course ```extern "C"``` only changes the linkage, but as the keyword suggests, it is used to bring together C and C++ code. 2) The problem described in the question could of course arise in other contexts, but I think that I made a case concrete enough: in fact I have obtained a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isolating library code in a single compilation unit and wrapping it with your own interface is actually a very common design task. Apparently you are pretty close to what you want with your solution, except for the void type pointer.

A forward declaration could fix that for you, but I assume `myCtype` is a `typedef`? If so, I would for once advise breaking isolation a little bit and looking into the library header. Say `myCtype` is defined as follows:

```c
typedef struct _myCtype {
  // Members...
} myCtype
```

Then your C++ header can look like this:

```cpp
class mywrapper
{
    struct _myCtype *v;
    // More members...
}
```

Notice how for this to work, `mywrapper.hpp` does not need to include the `myCtype.h` header, since it's a forward declaration. But in your `mywrapper.cpp`, if you include `myCtype.h` at the top, the member `v` will be treated like a proper `myCtype` pointer without the need for casts.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, ```myCtype``` is a ```typedef``` of a struct. I guess your solution would also work if one define ```mywrapper::v``` as ```_myCtype``` (i.e., not a pointer, but a normal variable), right?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Forward declarations only work with pointers (or references). If you declare `mywrapper::v` as a non-pointer type, then the compiler needs to know the details of `struct _myCtype`, e.g. how large it is when allocating an instance of `mywrapper`. Since all pointers are the same length, that's not necessary with a `_myCtype *` pointer. This mechanism is the basis of all forward declarations.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Just another question: in ```mywrapper.cpp``` does the order of ```#include "mywrapper.hpp"``` and ```#include "myCtype.h"``` matter?

Comment: You're welcome. Are you going to accept my answer as the correct solution then? And no, don't worry. It doesn't matter if the actual definition or the declaration comes first in your `.cpp` file. So long as everything's declared before its first use, and the members are defined before you first access them, the compiler will be happy.