# Using operator new in mixed c and c++ code

Tags: c++, c, malloc, language-lawyer, new-operator

Consider a program with mixed C and C++ code. The C++ part contains a class which dinamically allocates a C-style `typedef struct`. Minimal example:

**obj.h** (C-code)

```
typedef struct _Ctype {
  int i;
} Ctype;
```

**class.hpp** (C++ code)

```
struct A {
  struct _Ctype *x;
  A(int i);
  ~A();
};
```

**class.cpp** (C++ code)

```
#include "class.hpp"

extern "C" {
#include "obj.h"
}


A::A(int i)
{
  x = new struct _Ctype;
  x->i = i;
}

A::~A()
{
  delete(x);
}
```

**main.cpp** (C++ code, main program)

```
#include "class.hpp"

int main()
{
  A a(3);
  return 0;
}
```

(The rationale for this design originates from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52094011/8769985))

Is it safe (i.e., no UB) to use a `new` expression to allocate a C-style type `struct _Ctype`, as in the code above, or should one better use the C-style `malloc`/`free`?

**class.cpp** (C++ code, alternative)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "class.hpp"

extern "C" {
  #include "obj.h"
  }


A::A(int i)
{
  x = (struct _Ctype *)malloc(sizeof(struct _Ctype));
  x->i = i;
}

A::~A()
{
  free(x);
}
```

**ADDITION**

To clarify the question after some comments below: In the minimal example above, all the code is compiled with a C++ compiler. One can however think to use the C++ code in conjunction with a C library. The question can then be reformulated as follows:

- If I allocate memory for an C-style `typedef struct` via a C++ code, can the C library *safely* use the allocated variable? If so, are the alternatives given above both safe?

Note that one could also think to allocate the memory for `Ctype` through a C function, so that the C++ code only manages a pointer to it, for example:

**obj.h** (C-code)

```
typedef struct _Ctype {
  int i;
} Ctype;

Ctype *allocate_Ctype();
void deallocate_Ctype(Ctype* p);
```

**obj.C** (C-code)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "obj.h"

Ctype *allocate_Ctype()
{
   return (Ctype *)malloc(sizeof(Ctype));
}

void deallocate_Ctype(Ctype *p)
{
   free(p);
}
```

**class.cpp** (C++ code)

```
#include "class.hpp"

extern "C" {
#include "obj.h"
}


A::A(int i)
{
  x = allocate_Ctype();
  x->i = i;
}

A::~A()
{
  deallocate_Ctype(x);
}
```

(Note: of course the copy constructor and operator assignment of class A need to be properly defined, the code serves as illustration of the question)

Comment: you are not using "placement new"

Comment: 1. You're asking about placement `new`, but there is no placement `new` in your code. Where are you trying to add it, and why? 2. A name like `_Ctype` (starting with unerscore followed by cap) is reserved for the compiler/library in C++, and must not be used in user code.

Comment: It is never safe to `new` a C type... however, you have wrapped the C struct inside of a class... so you are using `new` on a C++ class, which is fine.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Erm, what? There are no "C types" in C++ code, really. But note that the OP is using `new` of the struct which they (it seems) intend to be accessible from C, not on the class `A`. (Not that it matters, it would be fine either way).

Comment: @bolov Sorry, bad terminology, I fixed it now

Comment: @Angew The question deals with a mixing of C and C++ code, assuming that I do not have control on the C part (e.g., by using a C library, see the linked question)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer The struct _Ctype is defined in the C header.

Comment: When the contents of the .h file are compiled by C++ compiler, then it is C++ code (brcause that is what C++ compiler processes).

Comment: This is not really mixed C and C++. It seems all your translation units are C++.

Comment: @hyde Yes, in the above example all the code is compiled by a c++ compiler. But I am thinking of a case of using a C library, which includes obj.h as header and it is compiled with a C compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the deallocation only ever happens under your control and using a `delete` expression, there is no problem at all. The C code interacting with the structure does not care how it was allocated.

Side note: the name `_Ctype` is not legal in C++, as it starts with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter. Such names (as well as names containing double underscore) are reserved for the compiler & standard library.

Comment: it's worth noting they can use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` to follow rule of zero anyway. Even if this requires a custom deallocator they can just [write a deleter.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)